# How to make ffmpeg realy silen without to use another process

Tags: ruby, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg in a ruby code like this :

```
fork { exec "ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -y #{path} -r 22050" }
```

It sends the pid of the created process. In the trace, I have this :

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
psize=     832kB time=4.52 bitrate=1507.4kbits/s    6.1kbits/s    its/s    
size=     963kB time=5.14 bitrate=1536.1kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:963kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.004664%
```

I want to make it quiet. I tried to add `-loglevel panic` and `-v 0` but it does not work. I know, I can add this `>/dev/null 2>&1` but it create another process and my method send only the pid of the first process.

Is there a way to make ffmpeg realy silent without to create another process?

Answer (score 1):

Try `-loglevel quiet` as a global option (the very first option and before the input options) as in:

```
fork { exec "ffmpeg -loglevel quiet -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -y #{path} -r 22050" }
```

See the docs on [FFmpeg Generic Options](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Generic-options) for more info.